# error: DataSource debe ser el identificador de un control del tipo IDataSource? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Hola tengo el siguiente gridview en asp .Net

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CssClass="table table-bordered bs-table" 
       allowpaging="True" ShowFooter="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White"  DataKeyNames="">
```

habia creado una consulta con SqlDataSource pero no era lo que yo queria
y necesito la consulta SQL del salo del servidor, y la cree asi en un boton con evento onclick, para que cuando le diera click me mostrara los registros en la tabla:

```
protected void Mostrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());

                string sql = "SELECT bla bla.. WHERE(Sem.Semana = '52') AND(Cab.Cod_user = '@cod');

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
                cmd.Parameters["@cod"].Value = Session["Cod_user"];
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                grid1.DataSource = rdr;
                grid1.DataBind();

            }
```

pero me muestra el error del titulo por estas lineas.....

```
 grid1.DataSource = rdr;
 grid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

carga el reader dentro de un datatable para luego asignarselo al grid.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rdr);
grid1.DataSource = dt;
grid1.DataBind();
```